# UIView Animation Chaining Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to animate a simple **Loading** label text to show 3 dots after it, with each dot having a second of delay.

Here is what i tried:

```
func animateLoading() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.yukleniyorLabel.text = "Yükleniyor."}, completion: { _ in
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.yukleniyorLabel.text = "Yükleniyor.."}, completion: { _ in
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.yukleniyorLabel.text = "Yükleniyor..."})
        })
    })
}
```

But what i got is the all 3 dots appear in 1 second alltogether. Not in order. See here: https://streamable.com/yiz6s

What am i doing wrong with the chaining? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIView `animate` is only for animatable view properties such as frame and background color. `self.yukleniyorLabel.text` is not an animatable property. So you get no animation.

Just use a Timer or delayed performance to change the text at time intervals.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Can you explain why it doesn't at least wait for completion (1 second delay) to show the new dot? Even if it's not animatable why does it jump to completion without waiting?

Comment: That is what I explained. You do not ask for any animatable property changes so your `animate` calls are irrelevant. I told you how to fix it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scheduled Timer for showing text with three dots on the label with animation: ->

```
var i = 0
var timer : Timer?

loaderLabel.text = "Loading"
timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector:#selector(ViewController.setText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


@objc func setText() {
    loaderLabel.text = loaderLabel.text! + "."
    i += 1
    if i >= 3 {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

output with animation: -> Loading...